# Add week in a table within SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am looking to add a computed column to a table that contains dates

```
select datepart(wk, '01-01-2020')
1

select datepart(wk, '12-29-2019')
53----result wanted 52
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ISO_WEEK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#iso_week-datepart):

```
select datepart(iso_week,'01-01-2020')

select datepart(iso_week,'12-29-2019')
```

From the docs:

> ISO 8601 includes the ISO week-date system, a numbering system for
>   weeks. Each week is associated with the year in which Thursday occurs.
>   For example, week 1 of 2004 (2004W01) covered Monday, 29 December 2003
>   to Sunday, 4 January 2004. European countries / regions typically use
>   this style of numbering. Non-European countries / regions typically do
>   not use it.
>
> Note: the highest week number in a year could be either 52 or 53.

You can play with [SET DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), too:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

SELECT @@DATEFIRST

select datepart(week,'01-01-2020') -- 1

select datepart(week,'12-29-2019') -- 52

select datepart(week,'12-30-2019') -- 53
```

If you are not able to populate this value on `insert/update` and you are not sure who is going to perform operation over the table, you can create a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[X]
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[Date] DATETIME2
   ,[Week] TINYINT
);

GO

CREATE TRIGGER [T] ON [dbo].[X] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    SET DATEFIRST 1;

    UPDATE [dbo].[X]
    SET [Week] = DATEPART(WEEK,A.[Date])
    FROM [dbo].[X] A
    INNER JOIN inserted B
        ON A.[ID] = B.[ID]

END;

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[X] ([Date])
VALUES ('01-01-2020')
      ,('12-29-2019')
      ,('12-30-2019');

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[X];
```

Comment: select datepart(iso_week,'12-30-2019') I will get 1, I need to 53.

Comment: @csharp What about this?

Comment: yes! it seems great! but how I can set @@DATEFIRST in a computed column?

Comment: That will be tricky. Consider populating this column with a trigger?

Comment: I don't know trigger. I am a very newbie within sql

Comment: @csharp I have added an example, but please, before use it in your real scenario - take some time to read about triggers.

Comment: Can I use a function instead of a trigger? A trigger seems complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207338/discussion-between-gotqn-and-csharp).